# Keycloak: permanent API key

Tags: api, authorization, keycloak, access-token, idp

I was searching a lot for a way to generate permanent tokens for users in Keycloak, and have discovered a few ways but no one of them really met my needs. Now, I'm thinking to develop another application to map user access/refresh tokens to a API Key and manage the refresh of access tokens in order to achieve permanent API Keys.

Before that, it could be interesting to get that point up before. Is there a way to generate permanent access tokens (let's call it API Keys) for a user without passing the authorization flow (flexible), and without changing all the realm expiration time? It would be good a way to revoke the tokens, regardless of what it is.

What I'm searching here is a native (hidden) function in Keycloak or one user extension/application to do it.

Thank you for the attention.

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: Hi, @Markoo91. We used Keycloak Token Exchange functionality to exchange opaque API Keys for fresh access tokens during the user request (reverse proxy before APIGW), since we could not implement the exchange flow in the back-ends.